# Python-3 Minecraft UUID to Username using the Requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, uuid

I am wondering if it is possible to take a minecraft UUID and convert it into the users current username. I know how to get all of there previous usernames, but I dont know how to single out the newest one, I am able to do this with the mojang API.

```
import requests
data = requests.get("https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/UUID/names")
print(data.content)
```

Comment: You should remove the solution from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

I figured it out, I did the following.

```
data = requests.get("https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/uuid").json()
print(data["name"])
```

NOTE: The UUID must be given with out dashes ("-")

Answer (score 2):

this should work but it has no parseing

```
r = requests.get(f'https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/notchat=0').json()
uuid = r['id']
r2 = requests.get(f'https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/{uuid}/names').json()
print(r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few lines of code can do the trick.

```
import requests

uuid = ["enter UUID here"]
#uuid can be a list or a single string

for i in uuid:
    data = requests.get(f"https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/{i}").json()
    print(data["name"])
```

Good for converting mass amounts of UUID's into IGNs without using namemc. Hope this helped.